# What exactly $event object do in Angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular, event-handling

I am bit confused what exactly `$event` doing here and what is the difference between this two examples

```
<button (click)="clicked($event)"></button>

@Component(...)
class MyComponent {
  clicked(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

and

```
<button (click)="clicked()">Click</button>



 @Component(...)
    class MyComponent {
      clicked(event) {
      }
    }
```

Comment: @Brian We generally do not pass `event` argument as part of attribute value, but handler does have that argument `function clickHandler(event){..}`(if required). I think OP should know, how events work in DOM, as shown [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Front-end-programming/blob/master/4_Javascript_Programming/Topic8_DOM_Access/DOM_interface_hierarchy.png)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`$event` is the event itself.

The event binding `(someevent)` allows to bind to DOM events and to `EventEmitter` events. The syntax is exactly the same.

For DOM events `$event` is the `MouseEvent`, `KeyboardEvent`, or the event value of the type of whatever event you listen to.

For `EventEmitter` events the emitted value is available as `$event`

Assuming this example `$event` refers to the emitted `Ferrari` car instance:

```
@Output() carChange:EventEmitter<Car> = new EventEmitter<Car>();

someMethod() {
  this.carChange.emit(new Car({name: 'Ferrari'}));
}
```

If you don't use `$event` like in `(click)="clicked()"` then the event value is not passed.

Actually as far as I remember it *is still passed in some browsers* but not in all (don't remember which ones)

But if you use Angulars WebWorker feature, then your method might not get the fired or emitted event if you don't explicitely list it.

Comment: I think `$event` is one of the type of events(`UIEvent`/`MouseEvent` ) in this [hierarchy](https://github.com/shamhub/Front-end-programming/blob/master/4_Javascript_Programming/Topic8_DOM_Access/DOM_interface_hierarchy.png). Is that correct?

Comment: In the browser it's `MouseEvent` for `(click)`, for outputs, it can be any type.

Comment: `click= f()`In HTML with JavaScript, we do no pass `event` in the handler. But the handler definition does have the parameter. `function  f(e){.... }`

Comment: I've also seen this approach, passing `this`: `<mycomponnent>  (selected_course)="changed(this)"</mycomponent>`. Does that reference the component or event?

Comment: The component, but that's usually pointless because the handler has access to `this` anyway, except perhaps if you don't use arrpw functions.

Comment: Is there any syntax for this `$` thing?

Comment: @MinhNghĩa what do you mean with "syntax"? It's just an identifier available in the scope of the event binding expression.

Comment: I thought the codes between the quotes are pure JS. Thanks for pointing it out for me.

Comment: No, they are Angular specific, but most TypeScript (and JS) expressions work. The scope is limited to the component (you can't use types (like `new Foo()`) or casting or enums (workarounds exists with functions, getters, fields in the component or pipes) or anything else from the global scope. Additionally the `?.` (safe-navigation operator) is supported.

Comment: this video beautifully explains the use of event handling: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfIc1_oj7uM&list=PLC3y8-rFHvwhBRAgFinJR8KHIrCdTkZcZ&index=9

Answer (score 2):

If you don't pass the `$event` in your template, then you won't have the `$event` variable in your `clicked()` method available.

> See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LXAijXqHnnrB0NVbAdHj?p=preview) for a quick comparison

Comment: Haha, it did back then. Looking at the default Plunker SystemJS `config.js` it seems, that it always uses the most current Angular 2 version. Where did `bootstrap` move to? I didn't follow the TS development for a while since I switched to the Dart version. Thanks to zoechi for enlightening me :D

Answer (score 0):

it holds all the values of an event. Like if you give an input what was the input.