# is $event.target.value a javascript command or a vue.js command?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this line in my vue.js application

```
<input type="text" v-on:input="cssClass=$event.target.value">
```

I know that in javascript I can get event.target.value. I think that the above code is Vue.js specific code, but I'm not sure. Need confirmation.

Comment: you are using a custom attribute `v-on:input...` so it's not default to javascript

Comment: if I take out the dollar sign, the vue.js application doesn't work. So this is a vue.js code right? :)

Comment: sorry, I forgot to specify. I was wondering specifically about the '$event' part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`v-on:input` will consume the actual DOM event of the `input` initially, store against `$event`, a special variable, and then make it available to the function being called. In this case you access `$event.target.value` to get the newly input value from the event. [Methods in Inline Handlers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $event because of VueJS. Angular2 also has the same special variable.
[What exactly $event object do in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944199/what-exactly-event-object-do-in-angular-2)