# Can the $events variable be renamed in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, events

I have the following Angular component:

```
import { Component, OnInit , EventEmitter , Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-corkpit',
  templateUrl: './corkpit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./corkpit.component.css']
})
export class CorkpitComponent implements OnInit {

  /* 
    @Output is used when you need to emit an event from a child 
    component to the parent (Opp. to what @Input does in the server component !) 
  */
  @Output() serverCreated = new EventEmitter<{ serverName: string , serverContent: string }>();
  @Output() blueprintCreated = new EventEmitter<{ serverName: string , serverContent: string }>();

  newServerName = '';
  newServerContent = '';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onAddServer() {
    this.serverCreated.emit({ 
      serverName : this.newServerName , 
      serverContent: this.newServerContent 
    })
  }

  onAddBlueprint() {
    this.blueprintCreated.emit({ 
      serverName : this.newServerName , 
      serverContent: this.newServerContent 
    })
  }

}
```

As you can see I have two function in which I am emitting events, like so:

```
  onAddServer() {
    this.serverCreated.emit({ 
      serverName : this.newServerName , 
      serverContent: this.newServerContent 
    })
  }

  onAddBlueprint() {
    this.blueprintCreated.emit({ 
      serverName : this.newServerName , 
      serverContent: this.newServerContent 
    })
  }
```

Now in the template file of the parent component, I have the following markup:

```
<app-corkpit
  (serverCreated)="onServerAdded($event)" 
  (blueprintCreated)="onBlueprintAdded($event)" 
  ></app-corkpit>
```

Here you see that on fire of the serverCreated event, the following function is called:

```
onServerAdded($event)
```

The function has a variable passed to it `$event` now if I change this `$event` to say `$data` my app breaks, so my question is can this `$event` variable not be renames to anything that I like? Just like in jQuery if a function accepts an event as an argument, it can be either `event` or just `e` or pretty much anything that I like.

Comment: i don't think you can rename  $event . As it's not acting like argument name in function. refers these link it may be of some help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944199/what-exactly-event-object-do-in-angular-2
and
https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Comment: Why do you want to change?

Comment: @LogicBlower Thanks.... Vega , no reason , just was curious .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to rename `$event` except forking the Angular repository and modifying its code.

There is also no point in renaming because it would only make it harder for others to understand the code without any benefit worth mentioning.