# How to call a function($event) manually in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I wrote a function with $event in Angular2 and through click event from template class it's working fine. But I am trying to call that function manually, So for that how to pass a event value through function.

This is my function:

```js
onActionChange($event) {
 // alert($event.target.value);
    const selectedAction = parseInt($event.target.value);
    }
```

This is how i am trying to call function:
onActionChange('7');

Here I am getting error like:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

Comment: Well your function expects an event parameter and you're passing a string to it, so I wonder what could have caused this error message

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944199/what-exactly-event-object-do-in-angular-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebuid a similar object:

```
onActionChange({target: {value: '7'}});
```

Or split your code with something similar:

```
onActionChange($event) {
  setAction(parseInt($event.target.value));
}

setAction(value) {
  const selectedAction = value;
}
```

Then you're free to call

```
setAction(7)
```

Answer (score 0):

To call it manually with `onActionChange(7)`

```
onActionChange($event) {
  const selectedAction = $event.target ? parseInt($event.target.value) : $event
  console.log('selectedAction', selectedAction)
}
```

This assumes that the value passed when you manually call it is numeric.