# Event Emitter Binding

Tags: angular, angular-event-emitter

I am going through "Angular Up and Running" by Shyam Seshadri, published by O'Reilly. In the discussion on Output and the emitting of events I'm a little confused.

The EventEmitter in a component is declared, initialized and implemented as:

```
@Output() private toggleFavorite: EventEmitter<Stock>;

constructor() {
 this.toggleFavorite = new EventEmitter<Stock>();
}

onToggleFavorite(event) {
 console.log('We are toggling the favorite state for this stock.', event);
 this.toggleFavorite.emit(this.stock);
}
```

The binding in the app.component.html reads:

```
(toggleFavorite)="appToggleFavorite($event)"
```

But the method in app.component.ts is defined as:

```
appToggleFavorite(stock: Stock) {
 console.log('Favorite for stock ', stock, ' was triggered.');
}
```

If the binding is passing the $event object, and the bound method is expecting a Stock type, why does this work?

(And it does work, I've tested it.)

I am not asking what the $event object does, I already know that. Please re-read my question above carefully. I am asking: when a bound function is expecting a typed parameter, why is a binding to an EventEmitter object passing the $event object instead of an object of the expected type, and why does it seem to work (the parameter gets it's values as typed.)

Comment: Stock is just a types and if you will use `any` there, it will also work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly $event object do in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944199/what-exactly-event-object-do-in-angular-2)

Comment: No, I am not asking what the $event object does, I already know that. Please do not be off-hand, but re-read my question again carefully. Thank you.

Comment: Well, `$event` is just variable name (reserved angular keyword used to pass event payload to be precise), not a type. In your example, its type is `Stock`. Not really sure where is the question then...

Comment: Why, then, isn't the stock parameter, regardless of type, being replaced with the $event object and all of it's parts? Instead, it is being populated with the correct data for the Stock in question. But how?

Comment: I think some crossover is happening involving the this.toggleFavorite.emit(this.stock); line in the declaring/implementing component (above.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, the `$event` is unecessary and create confusion.

```
(toggleFavorite)="appToggleFavorite()"
```

will work as well, since you're implying that when you call `.emit`, you will call `appToggleFavorite` with any value type given to `.emit`. And Javascript is an untyped language, so it will work at run time.

Comment: THANK YOU! This answer and the next clarified what I thought might be happening but was having trouble articulating!

Comment: The Stock is something that the Parent Component wants in the first place. Why waste creating an `Output` property if it wasn't to be used?

Comment: Don't forget to add points and accept the most usefull answer.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be, carefully have a look at the `appToggleFavorite` function below.

```
appToggleFavorite(stock: Stock) {
 console.log('Favorite for stock ', stock, ' was triggered.');
}
```

If it were to be called at **Compile time**, it would have thrown an error saying that `appToggleFavorite` is expecting an arg of type `Stock` but isn't given one.

But `appToggleFavorite` is getting called at **runtime**, and at runtime, its just HTML and JavaScript. It doesn't care what is received as an `arg` to `appToggleFavorite`. And thus it works.

Just to give you a brief, the Child Component can let the Parent Component know about something via an `Output` property on it. This `Output` property will then be used by the Parent Component's Template as an `event`. So to listen for the `Output` property, an Event Binding would be required. The Handler Function that is assigned to this Event Binding will be called as soon as the `emit` method is called on the `EventEmitter` that was exposed as an `Output` property. The Handler function will only be able to get a hold of the data that was passed to the `emit` function **only if the reserved keyword `$event`** is used.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to see the two compile stages as this code is broken down into Javascript, I think I might better understand what's going on "behind the curtain" here, so to speak. Somehow the stock parameter is getting populated with correct data, even though the binding is passing the $event object instead. Why?

Comment: Like I said, it's being called at runtime. It's basically a handler to an event which like any DOM Event would be called at runtime, in the future, after the App has compiled.

Comment: Okay, maybe I'm being slow here, but wouldn't the parameter then hold the data for $event and all if it's parts? It isn't, it's getting the stock data it needs. Where is it getting it, if $event is being passed instead?

Comment: No. It would hold only the data that was emitted here:  `this.toggleFavorite.emit(this.stock);`

Comment: Thank you, that's the answer I was locking for.

Answer (score 0):

It's a *Advanced Type* of **TypeScript**, not from Angular. When you declare:

```
@Output() private toggleFavorite: EventEmitter<Stock>;
```

The type of `toggleFavorite` is `<Stock>` and the compiler is "*waiting*" this type in return of value.
The doc of this is right [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

Comment: I don't think it's because of Generics. `@Output() private toggleFavorite: EventEmitter<any>;` would work as well.

Comment: THANK YOU! This answer and the prior one clarified what I thought might be happening but was having trouble articulating!

Comment: Yes, because `<any>` accept anything. If you put `<Stock>` will accept `<foo>`?

Comment: Yeah, but according to your point, it should work in case of the `appToggleFavorite(stock: Stock)` as it's only accepting `Stock` but is given any. But it would work.

Comment: It's just for _protect/clarify_  your code, if you want to be free, put `any` and like @SiddAjmera said will accept anything

Comment: Yes, the `onToggleFavorite` return type is `any`, if he puts `onToggleFavorite(event: foo)` may cause error

Comment: Sorry, i know what's wrong now, I will edit my answer