# Can't use any other variable name than $event for reception of the emitted number in Angular

Tags: angular, eventemitter

*NB. The question is not **how** to make it work (since I can, as explained at the bottom). It's rather about **why** I can make it work this way and no other.*

I've designed a component like this. It's a data row that can keep a bunch och data rows. Hence, in each such instance, we have both *onRemoval* (invoked when the user clicks on remove icon) as well as *onRemove* (invoked when the emitted even is heard).

```
@Output() remove: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
...
onRemoval() {
  console.log("being removed: " + this.id);
  this.remove.emit(this.id);
}
onRemove(id: number) {
  console.log("removing: " + id);
  if (!id)
    return;

  this.subRows.splice(id, 1);
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something stupid but what puzzles me when I try to debug it is that the emitted value is the correct index, while the received value isn't. It's *undefined*.

The relevant part of the markup I've tried looks like this. I also tried with empty parantheses, as well as no parantheses.

```
<div *ngIf="unfolded">
  <app-data-row *ngFor="let subRow of subRows"
                (remove)="onRemove(id)"
                [config]="subRow"></app-data-row>
</div>
```

I've googled this but as far I could tell, I've followed the proper approach by using *EventEmitter*. Also, it seems that the setup works as far as that the event is emitted and received. It's just the *id* value that seems not to be set properly.

The only way to make it work is to call the variable **precisely** *$event* and nothing else. Is that me doing something dumb or is that the required syntax?! I mean, not even *$id$ helped...

Comment: You can read it [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-and-event-handling-statements) in the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In template, when connecting child's output to component's callback: `$event` is the name of the emitted value, and there's no way around that. After all: invoking the handler doesn't *need* to have the output as its sole argument. You could do, dunno,

```
<app-data-row *ngFor="let subRow of subRows" (remove)="onRemove(subRow.id)">
```

or

```
<app-data-row *ngFor="let subRow of subRows" (remove)="onRemove(subRow.id, $event)">
```

or

```
<app-data-row *ngFor="let subRow of subRows" (remove)="onRemove($event, subRow.id)">
```

and so on, and so forth. So, here in the template, `$event` is needed as the identifier of the actual output value.

Comment: Now that you say this way, it makes perfect sense. I guess this was the kind of day when one gets unlucky while trying to think, hehe.

Answer (score 1):

`$event` is the event itself when using `@Output` event emitter of component/directive that emits the value and it is captured by the callback function with `$event` variable.

When you define event listener with parenthesis such as

`(remove)="onRemove($event)"`

you actually pass a method reference. You don't need a local variable defined before. And Angular itself replaces the `$event` value with the emitted one. But if you do it like

`(remove)="onRemove(id)"`

it considers `id` to be a local variable such as you define in `*ngFor="let id of idList"`

In short, it is the only way to capture the emitted value when using output event emitter of a component/directive.

You can have a look at this official docs: https://angular.io/guide/user-input

And also this SO thread: [What exactly $event object do in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944199/what-exactly-event-object-do-in-angular-2)