# Angular data passing child to parent not responding

Tags: angular, angular-event-emitter

I have a list of data in table from array and I am displaying form on the click on `Add User` button which is working fine.

But I also want to hide the form on click of `cancel` button which doesn't seem working. I followed the docs from angular regarding event emitter. The data is not transmitting to parent on click event.

I have created a demo. Please help.

[Stackbliz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-child-to-parent-not-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your event is not attached to `<app-add-user-form>` but to `<tr>`. To make it work write it like:

```
      <tr *ngIf="showForm === true">
        <td colspan="3">
          <app-add-user-form (showUserForm)="hideUserForm($event)"></app-add-user-form>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: In addition to this it is also better practice to use triple equals in typescript, like *ngIf="showForm === true" or just do *ngIf="showForm"

Comment: Ohh. so I just can't use that eventEmitter data anywhere in the parent ?

Comment: parent should know which child exactly emits

Comment: in `app.component.ts line 25 {res: undefined}` it shows undefined. it should be false isn't it ?

Comment: My bad, its $event instead of val. I've adjusted the answer and also changed the ngIf to strict equality as @canpan14 pointed out.

Comment: Thanks for correcting it. Is `$event` a reserve variable from angular. I can't use anything inside it ?

Comment: if i may https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944199/what-exactly-event-object-do-in-angular-2

Comment: Thanks @Smollet777